# To what degree are wind and water turbines exchangeable?

Tags: turbines, renewable-energy, wind-power

Assuming maximum efficiency is not the *primary* concern (but net positive efficiency is), to what extent could a wind turbine operate in water and vice versa?

How do the different turbine types fare in this respect? I.e., HAWT / VAWT (Savonius, Darrieus, Gorlov) for air turbines, reaction (Francis, Kaplan, Gorlov) / impulse (Turgo, Jonval) turbines (Pelton wheels are probably out) for water turbines?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering.SE.  As it is written, your question is basically a "looking for references" question, which is outside the scope of our format.  In other words, we are not here to do your research for you.  If you have a concise question to ask, that is more fitting with this site.  You would be better suited performing some research on your own, formulating your views, and then asking for clarification on the points in which you are lacking understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I actually did research the topic, but came up with no real results. Also, not being a professional engineer or student of engineering, I don't really have access to a lot of the publications. Of course, I'd be grateful for a point in the right direction where to look.

Answer (score 5):

Given that water is roughly 1000× as dense as air, and incompressible besides, it should be fairly obvious: A wind turbine would be destroyed by the forces that water would put on it, and a water turbine wouldn't even notice the forces created by wind.

Comment: Certainly seems obvious, thanks! But say I were to limit the number of revolutions per minute in water and use something like a vertical helical turbine, made out of carbon fiber? For argument's sake, let's make the blades about a meter in length - that would give me around a third of a square meter under water. Should be kind of manageable, right?

Comment: @Zubo That sounds less like exchanging a water turbine for a wind turbine than like designing a new turbine altogether. Is there something in particular you're trying to accomplish?